# Run-Time Type Comparisons Within a Generic Hierarchy in java

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I am unable to understand this text from **The Complete Reference**
The code is this,

```
public class Generic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SuperClass<Integer> s1=new SuperClass<>(135);
        SubClass<Double> s2=new SubClass<>(1.35);
        if(s1 instanceof SuperClass<Integer>)
        {
            System.out.println("I am instance of SuperClass");
        }
    }
}

class SuperClass<T>
{
    T y;
    SuperClass(T ob)
    {
        y=ob;
    }
    T ret()
    {
        return(y);
    }
}

class SubClass<T> extends SuperClass<T>
{
    T x;
    SubClass(T y)
    {
        super(y);
        x=y;
    }
}
```

According to the text,

> `if(s1 instanceof SuperClass<Integer>)` this line can’t be compiled because it attempts to compare s1 with a specific type of `SuperClass`,in this case, `SuperClass<Integer>`. Remember, there is no generic type information available at run time. Therefore, there is no way for `instanceof` to know if `s1` is an instance of `SuperClass<Integer>` or not.

Can someone please explain me what exactly these lines mean?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @RedRoboHood-I thought that generic type information is available only at run time,but here it says that it is not available at run time

Comment: erasure is the root of all evils.

Comment: @RajMalhotra On the contrary: generic type information is purely a compile-time tool. It's used to check things *at* compile time so that any possible problems relating to generic types can be avoided *before* runtime.

Comment: Based on what I read about Generics, they're basically designed to save programmers from their own stupidity. Instead of having to trace your steps because you cast something incorrectly, the compiler will tell you that it's supposed to be this class/class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

When your .java file is compiled into .class file, also known as byte code, `SuperClass<Integer>` this piece of code gets converted to `SuperClass`. This is called as type erasure. So at runtime there is no information about generic type.

Comment: @Amit.rk3- and what happens if I write SuperClass<?>,it compiles fine,why?

Comment: @RajMalhotra '?' is a wildcard for 'anything'. So `SuperClass<?>` is equivalent to `SuperClass`

Answer (score 1):

Generics information is a compile-time feature. It is erased at runtime. The error is explained in [this section of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> It is a compile-time error if the *ReferenceType* mentioned after the `instanceof` operator does not denote a reference type that is **reifiable** (§4.7).

And a *reifiable* type is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) as:

> **Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time.** Types that are completely available at run time are known as *reifiable types*.
>
> A type is *reifiable* if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> - It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.
> - **It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1)**.
> - It is a raw type (§4.8).
> - It is a primitive type (§4.2).
> - It is an array type (§10.1) whose element type is reifiable.
> - It is a nested type where, for each type T separated by a ".", T itself is reifiable.

Therefore, it is not allowed to have a parameterized type like `SuperClass<Integer>` as the reference type for `instanceof`. On the other hand, `SuperClass<?>` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath the hood, something called **Type erasure** happens when Generics are used. What this means is that generic types are converted to their raw (non-generic) forms during the process of compiling your program into bytecode. All type parameters simply become Object, and all values assigned to type variables are cast to Object. This is what's meant by "there is no generic type information available at run time".

A line such as

```
if(s1 instanceof SuperClass<Integer>)
```

becomes

```
if(s1 instanceof SuperClass)
```

after compilation. The problem with using `instanceof` on parameterized types is that during runtime, the Java VM cannot differentiate between types such as `SuperClass<Integer>` and `SuperClass<Double>`. If the compiler did allow `instanceof` to be used with parameterized types, the previous line would return true for `SuperClass<Double>` as well, which may produce undefined behavior.

If you want to know more, Oracle's website has a more thorough explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast